# How to use React Hooks in React standalone?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to use React Hooks in a standalone UMD environment. I am getting the below error

> Uncaught Invariant Violation: Minified React error #307;

The error is pointing me to https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html/?invariant=307

How do i use Hooks in this case? Below is my code:

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title>React Hooks</title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
    </head>
    <body>
        <!--[if lt IE 7]>
            <p class="browsehappy">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="#">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
        <![endif]-->
        <div id="root"></div>

        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
        <script src="App.js" async defer></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

App.js

```
var CounterText = function(props) {
    return React.createElement(
        'div',
        null,
        `You clicked ${props.count} times!`
    );
}

var ButtonCounter = function(props) {
    return React.createElement(
        'button',
        {className: 'btn', onClick: props.clickHandler},
        `Click Me!`
    );
}

var Counter = function() {
    var state = React.useState(0);
    var count = state[0];
    var setCount = state[1];

    return React.createElement(
        'div',
        {className: 'counter'},
        CounterText({count: 0}),
        ButtonCounter({})
    );
}

ReactDOM.render(
    Counter(),
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have rendered the `Counter` component incorrectly, you need to render it using `React.createElement` within `ReactDOM.render`. Also, even though the app will work even if you pass ButtonCounter and CounterText to React.createElement like

```
return React.createElement(
    'div',
    {className: 'counter'},
    CounterText({count: count}),
    ButtonCounter({clickHandler: updateCount})
);
```

its better that you pass on  the child elements by creating React element ot of them so that react can optimize on it. This is important specifically when `CounterText` and `ButtonCounter` also contains some logic from React.

Also you can pass down state and handlers to these components as props for a working application

```js
var CounterText = function(props) {
    return React.createElement(
        'div',
        null,
        `You clicked ${props.count} times!`
    );
}

var ButtonCounter = function(props) {
    return React.createElement(
        'button',
        {className: 'btn', onClick: props.clickHandler},
        `Click Me!`
    );
}

var Counter = function() {
    var state = React.useState(0);
    var count = state[0];
    var setCount = state[1];
    var updateCount = () => {
       setCount(count => count + 1)
    }
    return React.createElement(
        'div',
        {className: 'counter'},
        React.createElement(CounterText, {count: count}),
        React.createElement(ButtonCounter,{clickHandler: updateCount})
    );
}

ReactDOM.render(
    React.createElement(Counter),
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title>React Hooks</title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
    </head>
    <body>
        <!--[if lt IE 7]>
            <p class="browsehappy">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="#">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
        <![endif]-->
        <div id="root"></div>

        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
        <script src="App.js" async defer></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Couple of issues here, You shouldn't invoke your components like:

```
Counter()
```

React will do it by itself (lazy evaluation), so you need to wrap it with `createElement` as well.

For example:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  React.createElement(Counter),
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Another thing, you are not really using the `count` and `setCount`:

```
return React.createElement(
        'div',
        {className: 'counter'},
        CounterText({count: 0}),
        ButtonCounter({})
    );
```

Here is a running example:

```js
var CounterText = function(props) {
  return React.createElement(
    'div',
    null,
    `You clicked ${props.count} times!`
  );
}

var ButtonCounter = function(props) {
  return React.createElement(
    'button', {
      className: 'btn',
      onClick: props.clickHandler
    },
    `Click Me!`
  );
}

var Counter = function() {
  var state = React.useState(0);
  
  var count = state[0];
  var setCount = state[1];

  return React.createElement(
    'div', {
      className: 'counter'
    },
    React.createElement(CounterText,{
      count:count
    }),
    React.createElement(ButtonCounter,{clickHandler: () => setCount(c => c + 1)})
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(
  React.createElement(Counter),
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="App.js" async defer></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

add [babel standalone](https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.26.0/babel.min.js) in your app.
and  then you can use jsx and all other stuff, also you need to do this

```html
<script type="text/babel" src="App.js" async defer></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Functional components cannot be called directly in case they use hooks. `createElement` should be used for all components:

```
return React.createElement(
    'div',
    {className: 'counter'},
    React.createElement(CounterText, {count: 0}),
    React.createElement(ButtonCounter)
);
```